# Error when creating a topic with partition choosed on Spring Kafka

Tags: spring, kotlin, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'm learning to use Kafka using Spring Kafka in Kotlin. I understanded that when a new topic is published, it is created if not exists. So, when I send a value to a new/old topic created from Spring the default partition is 0, but I want write a message on another parition, like partition 1 for example.

When I create/write on a topic, it's works:

```
val topicTesteKotlin = "topico-teste-kotlin"

fun sendTopicCallback(@PathVariable message : String) : ResponseEntity<String> {
        val msg = Optional.of(message)
        return if (msg.isPresent) {
            kafkaTemplate.send(topicTesteKotlin, message).addCallback({
                println("Sent message=[" + message +
                        "] with offset=[" + it!!.recordMetadata.offset() + "]")
            }, {
                println("Unable to send message=["
                        + message + "] due to : " + it.message)
            })
            ResponseEntity.ok(msg.get())
        } else {
            kafkaTemplate.send(topicTesteKotlin, "GET /send_topic_callback/message BadRequest > $message")
            ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Bad request!")
        }
    }
```

But, when I choose the partition and key using:

```
val topicTesteKotlin = "topico-teste-kotlin"

fun sendTopicCallback(@PathVariable message : String) : ResponseEntity<String> {
        val msg = Optional.of(message)
        return if (msg.isPresent) {
            kafkaTemplate.send(topicTesteKotlin, 1, "1", message).addCallback({
                println("Sent message=[" + message +
                        "] with offset=[" + it!!.recordMetadata.offset() + "]")
            }, {
                println("Unable to send message=["
                        + message + "] due to : " + it.message)
            })
            ResponseEntity.ok(msg.get())
        } else {
            kafkaTemplate.send(topicTesteKotlin, "GET /send_topic_callback/message BadRequest > $message")
            ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Bad request!")
        }
    }
```

I got the follow error:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Invalid partition given with record: 1 is not in the range [0...1).
```

I tried change key to `0.1` but also not works. Apparentely when I create a topic from Spring client just a partition is created and that is `0`.

**Kafka Producer config**

```
@Configuration
class KafkaProducerConfig {

    @Bean
    fun producerFactory() : ProducerFactory<String, String> {
        val configProps = HashMap<String,Any>()
        configProps[ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG] = "localhost:9092"
        configProps[ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = StringSerializer::class.java
        configProps[ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = StringSerializer::class.java
        return DefaultKafkaProducerFactory(configProps)
    }

    @Bean
    fun kafkaTemplate() : KafkaTemplate<String, String> {
        return KafkaTemplate(producerFactory())
    }

}
```

So, how I create partition from Spring Kafka client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could manage topic creation mechanism by using the following code:

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaTopicConfig {
    @Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrapAddress}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;
    private String testTopicName = "topico-teste-kotlin";

    @Bean
    public KafkaAdmin kafkaAdmin() {
        Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
        configs.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,       bootstrapAddress);
    return new KafkaAdmin(configs);
    }
   @Bean
    public NewTopic testTopic() {
        // second parameter is a number of partitions
        return new NewTopic(testTopicName, 2, (short) 1);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, it's works. I just added the last function on my config producer. You can let me know how I check the topic readed on `@KafkaListener fun listenWithHeaders(@Payload message : String, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) partition : Int)` function?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't fully understand what would you like to do here? If you would like to read only specific partition you could specify @KafkaListener(topicPartitions= "") if you need to know  partition for current ConsumerRecord you can use @KafkaListener(topics = "myTopic")
    public void listen(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> cr) throws Exception {cr.partition();}